# Cannot insert into mysql table an image read from associative array

Tags: php, mysql

By reading the contents of a binary file (image) to a **$banner**

`$banner = addslashes (fread (fopen ( $mysql_banner, "r"),filesize($mysql_banner)))`

You can then easily put it in a MySQL database table. It works perfect.
But when you do a extra step by loading the contents of a binary file (image) to a associative 
 array **$final** for later insertion from it into the database,  a problem appears - that you can 
not insert it into the database table.
Let's put the same content into associative **$final**

`$final["banner"]  = addslashes( fread( fopen( $mysql_banner,"r"), filesize($mysql_banner)`

and decomposing it into components

```
 while ( list($name, $value) = each($final) )  {**
     $values_fields .= "$name, "; 
      $values .= "'$value', ";
}
$query1 = "INSERT INTO $banery ($values_fields) VALUES('$values')";
$res = mysql_db_query( $db, $query1)**
```

Although the original $banner and its copy a variable **$value** (taken from associative array 
**$final**) have the same content, (a binary content of image),  only the original **$banner** can be inserted into database. When I try to insert **$value**, the following warning is displayed: "- ***CAN NOT insert into the database. MySQL Insert - Something wrong*** ..." (enigmatic hint)
Why?`enter code here`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

You never defined

```
$banery
```

therefor you can't insert into it.

You have to do something like

```
INSERT INTO table_name (...
```

But you're doing

```
INSERT INTO $table_name (...
```

Without defining what $table_name (in your case, $banery) is

Comment: All needed variables are defined elswhere in the script and they work well. The problem is in retrieving data $value from associative $final. I put there good working $final["banner"] containg binary string and get back $value after the decomposition of $final, it contains the same binary string as stored original but it can be inserted. It is weird, maybe inside the "php is lost some pointer when apply the well-known syntax of "each decomposition.

Comment: To all GUYS to intrigue I say simplified:  I put the coin into the box ($final) and I get back (list..=..equal) a coin which looks identical but the system doesn't accept it.

Comment: The script executes the insertion very good if the inserted values is precisely named the concrete variable. AFTER when the same value is extracted from the associative $final , a name of field and a name of value are generalized and I think this may be the reason that the same value is no 100% identical when read from the computer's memory.